# make Julia show up on JupyterLab

Tags: julia, jupyter-lab

I have installed Julia (on Linux) at a location, say /a/b/c, along with IJulia, the kernel package required to make Julia show up on JupyterLab.  I would like this to be for a multi-user mode (I understand they will not have ability to install/maintain packages)

When I set $HOME to /a/b/c, JupyterLab shows the Julia kernel and everything seems to work.  This is not a viable solution for multiple reasons.

I tried a few different options, so far to no avail:
 - Created a softlink: ln -s /a/b/c/.julia /home/guru/.julia 
 - Set env variable JULIA_PROJECT to /a/b/c/.julia then to /a/b/c/.julia/environments/v1.0/ 
 - Also tried setting JULIA_PKGDIR but this seems to be obsolete anyway

What is the right way to have /a/b/c/.julia show up for everyone when they launch JupyterLab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the instructions here: it seems to require re-installing IJulia with the ENV["jupyter"] environment variable first set properly.

https://qiita.com/crowdy/items/d1e86df398ee97086d74

Comment: you do not need to reinstall - just run `build IJulia` in the package manager to rebuild.

Comment: Just checked the IJulia page at https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl and it does mention to set 'JUPYTER' env variable

Answer (score 1):

It seems that JupyterLab cannot find `julia` command. Because it is not in your `PATH`.

You can try the following command to create a link for your julia executable in a directory which is in `PATH`. The usual directory to do that is `/usr/local/bin`.

```
sudo ln -s /a/b/c/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

This should work for all users. Note that `/usr/local/bin` might not exist in some Linux distributions. If you have such a distribution, run `echo $PATH` in Linux command line to see which directories are in path.

Another solution would be to add julia's `bin` directory to `PATH` for all users.

```
sudo echo "export PATH=$PATH:/a/b/c/bin" >> /etc/profile
```

I would go for the first solution.

Comment: I just verifited that julia is in the path.  I installed everything inside a conda env.  Continuing with the hypothetical path, /a/b/c/.conda/envs/v2/bin/julia is in the PATH after activating the conda env (v2)

Comment: even if you install julia under the conda path, that won't make it executable. you need to have the julia executable in your path. so the julia/bin folder. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding Jupyter Lab to Julia via `Conda.jl` and just using this added version.

```
using Conda
Conda.add("jupyterlab")
```

Now run from the console:

```
~/.julia/packages/Conda/hsaaN/deps/usr/bin/jupyter lab
```

There are many other options so comment if you need something different.

Comment: Thanks but this seems to be installing yet another jupyter inside .julia directory.  I already have a conda environment including python/jupyter etc and I had installed julia as well, using 'conda install'.  I will also try suggestions by others and keep you all posted